# AES encryption in Java using any length password

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to encrypt a string in java with AES encryption using a password of any length.  Here is my code so far but I do not understand it very well:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String input, String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    return cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
}
```

How can I make a method to encrypt and decrypt a string of any length using a password of any length it.  Also what is salt?  I have been using the salt name for the password which only allows me to use a password of 16 characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java 256-bit AES Password-Based Encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption)

Comment: Do you understand what `ECB` means and what its limitations are? If not, please stop writing code until you have a basic idea of what you are doing. There is no hope code written this way will be secure.

Comment: Thanks for finding that for me @Duncan, I searched everywhere and couldn't find code like that

Comment: No I do not know what ECB means and what its limitations are @David Schwartx I have never done anything security/crypto related in my life

Comment: What is the meaning of ECB? @David Schwartz

Comment: @kzolp67 Rather than asking David for that information, try a bit of online research. There is a lot of advice out there regarding ECB-mode and why it is nearly always an inferior option to other encryption modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to encrypt/decrypt some data from a password, you need to use an algorithm which can generate from this password a key which is suitable for the cipher you want to use.

Java provides an implementation of PBKDF2 (Password based key derivation function).

```
char[] password = /* ... */
byte[] salt = /* ... */
SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 8192, 256);
SecretKey tmp = kf.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
```

Note that:

The salt is a **non secret** random byte array. It is used to avoid dictonnary based attack (see wikipedia [Rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) article for more details)

The iteration counts makes a brute-force attack more complex since an attack requires more resources whan the iteration count is larger. Today the iteration count should not be below 5000.